# DOS batch : append XML tags in unique TXT file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I need to list the content of `<AAA></AAA>` XML tags from several XML files into a unique TXT results file. Say I have a folder 'D:/folder' that contains several XML files.

Here is my code :

```
@echo off

cd D:/

for %%f in (folder/*.xml) do (

    for /f %%a in (%%f) do (

        for /f "delims=<AAA></AAA> tokens=2" %%b in ('echo "%%a" ^| Findstr /r  "<AAA>"') do echo %%b >> result.txt

    )

)
```

The code is doing the job for the first XML file but then cannot find the other ones... The Shell window shows error messages (see attached image ; sorry, it's in french).[image]

Comment: Use backslashes instead of normal slashes on your paths

Comment: Why use ancient batch command language. Using PowerShell will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"

FOR /f "tokens=3delims=<>" %%a IN ('findstr /L /c:"<AAA>" "%sourcedir%\*.xml"^|findstr /L /c:"</AAA>"') DO ECHO %%a

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

You don't show use what your real tags are; `"delims="` establishes a set of delimiter characters, not delimiter strings.

You may need to vary `tokens=3` to `tokens=2` if your `AAA` tag is not indented. If it may or may not be indented, then the routine would need to be varied a little.

It's probable that the second filter on the close-tag is not required. All depends on what you haven't told us - your *actual* layout.

This should work if the lines in question are

```
spaces<AAA>stingyouwant</AAA>whatever
```

Please also note `\` for directory-separators; `/` for command-switches.

Comment: Hello, thanks ! <AAA> tag is always preceeded by spaces (at least one tab) and never followed by something else on the same line. I tested your code but it doesn't work. The Shell window opens and closes down immediatly after, despite a 'pause' instruction...

Comment: That depends on where you put the `pause`. It should be put before the `goto :eof`. Batch programs are normally developed using a `cmd window` - Start>Programs>Accessories>Command Prompt - in fact, it's normally advisable to make a shortcut to `cmd` on the desktop. The big advantage is that when a batch finishes, you are returned to the prompt with the `echo`ed responses visible.