# Batch add xml lines after a specific line

Tags: xml, batch-file

I want to create a batch script which will do the following:
Find specific xml lines, and add specific multiline tags.

For example: Find exactly this set of lines:

```
<tree_node>
    <rule_name>bla</rule_name>
    <rule_argument>bla</rule_argument>
    <acl_name>bla</acl_name>
</tree_node>
```

Then add this set of lines afterwards:

```
<tree_node>
    <rule_name>TEST1</rule_name>
    <rule_argument>TEST2</rule_argument>
    <acl_name>TEST3</acl_name>
</tree_node>
```

An alternative solution would be to insert the tags at a specific line number.
Can anyone help with a solution? I have searched, but not found anything about my problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Related dbenham's answer: [Please note - parsing XML with batch is a risky business](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26718487/3439404)

Comment: Why not use a scripting language that can properly read and write XML files?  Vbscriipt, Jscript, Powershell.

Comment: It would be possible in Powershell- however I don't have any knowhow to do it. Any examples would be welcome. Thanks!